# Obtaining the stem of a word

Tags: computational-linguistics

I wonder if you know a computational method to obtain the stem of any English word. By stem I mean the part of the word which is never affected by plurals, temporal forms, and so on. For example, stem("cars") = car; stem("children") = child; stem ("tried") = try.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your examples seem like you are looking for **stems** (the form which inflectional affixes attach to) rather than **roots** (the smallest lexical morpheme which serves as the basis for composition/derivation/inflection). They are sometimes the same, but  e.g. in the word "teachers", the root would be "teach", but the part that undergoes inflection (which you seem to be interested in) is "teacher"; this is not the root, but the stem of the word. So, which one are you referring to?

Comment: I gave an answer to this in a comment which somehow got deleted.  That's irritating.  My answer is: Look it up in the dictionary.  Assuming there are only a finite number of words in the language, the root or stem for each word can be listed, and a very fast method is to simply look up the information in the list.  If you wanted a *cheap* or *convenient* method, the answer might be different.

Comment: Google for stemmer, specifically either Porter or Snowball for English.  They are surprisingly simple.

Comment: That thing is called "lemmatization"

Answer (score 3):

You might actually need the *lemma* of the word. *Stemming* and *lemmatizing* [are very similar](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html):

**Stemming** usually refers to a crude heuristic process that chops off the ends of words in the hope of achieving this goal correctly most of the time, and often includes the removal of derivational affixes.

**Lemmatization** usually refers to doing things properly with the use of a vocabulary and morphological analysis of words, normally aiming to remove inflectional endings only and to return the base or dictionary form of a word, which is known as the lemma .

Among the most commonly used NLP tools which also contain both stemming and lemmatizing are [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) and [CoreNLP](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're trying to stem English words, the easiest approach would probably be to use one of the existing applications of the Porter algorithm. Try [Snowball](http://snowballstem.org/) (it's also available as [GATE](https://gate.ac.uk/) and [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) plugins) - it's well-known in the NLP community, so you'll be able to get help fairly quickly.

An alternative is Krovetz stemming, of which a JAVA/C++ application is available [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/lemur/wiki/KrovetzStemmer/) (personally I haven't used this before, so I can't comment on its effectiveness).